# The car alarm system is blaring/yelling

Tags: idiomatic-language

When a car alarm system goes on, does it blare, yell, or something else?

> The car alarm system is blaring/yelling

Comment: It wouldn't yell, as that requires a person, but it could blare, wail or shriek

Comment: It's a good question; I don't think there is a commonly accepted description for the noise a car alarm makes. We all just wish it would quit; I've never known one to indicate that a car was being broken into.

Comment: ***Yelling*** is completely unacceptable here (normally, only "conscious entities" can "yell"). ***Blaring*** is acceptable, but it is somewhat "coloured, emotive". The default "neutral" verb for such contexts is [***The alarm sounded.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+alarm+sounded%22) That's an *intransitive* verb usage (the alarm emits sounds all by itself), as opposed to the *transitive* usage ***John sounded the alarm*** (John *caused* the alarm to emit sounds).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for the answer!

Comment: Oh, and somewhat counter-intuitively - when an alarms *starts* making a noise, we say it's gone ***off***, not ***on***. We *might* use ***on*** if the alarm had been *going on for ages*, because "to go on" can mean "do something continuously". But even there we'd probably say it'd [*been going **off** for ages!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22timer%27s+been+going+off+for+ages%22) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yelling would not be propriate for a car alarm, as yelling is usually [reserved for humans](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yell). The car alarm could definitely [blare](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blare) however, and it could also [wail](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wail) or [shriek](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shriek). The most idiomatic (depending on the context) would be blare in my opinion. I would also hesitate to use "car alarm system", instead just "car alarm".

Comment: One interesting thing, I agree about "yell", but the nearly identical meaning "scream" I am not so certain of.

Comment: i agree, scream is usually used in context of humans, but is also used to indicate loud, usually high pitched sounds eg. "the gate screaming as he opened it". same for shriek